# how to create a shape with min and max values power bi

Tags: powerbi, visualization, vega-lite, deneb

I have a data below:

```
xmin    xmax     ymin   ymax
 2        4      1       2
 4        6      2       3
```

I wanted to generate a shape which I can use to fill in values. Please assist.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by a "shape"?

Comment: For instance with xmin to xmax and ymin to ymax I wanted to draw a line ...so it kind of becomes rectangle

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? What isn't working? I suggest reading up on HTML and how to draw shapes using your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Create your data like this.

[image]

Make sure every column says do not aggregate.
Import the Deneb visual from marketplace.
Add the fields to the Deneb visual well as follows:

[image]

Paste the following code into Deneb.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "width": 300,
  "height": 240,
  "background": "white",
   "data": {"name": "dataset"},
  "layer": [
      {
      
      "mark": {"type": "rect", "color": "#9bc2e6"}
    }
  ],
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "xmin",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {"domain": [0, 10]}
    },
    "x2": {"field": "xmax"},
    "y": {
      "field": "ymin",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {"domain": [8, 0]}
    },
    "y2": {"field": "ymax"},
    "color":{"field": "id"}
  }
}
```

That's it.

Comment: Just one question please. Can i convert my x and y into table form?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: Like I have X and Y in the form of coordinates. I wanted to sketch a heatmap matrix using X and Y.

Comment: Yes, you can do that but there are easier ways to create a heat map. I suggest asking a new question with your requirements.